Free up rusted front shocks
I am trying to loosen these shocks. One of the things I am trying is to hit the fork to
loosen it up. That is after liberally applying a high grade rust loosener.
I have turned my bike upside down and tried hammering from the other end.
I noticed that the rust loosener drips out the bottom after I spray it on area where the piston is in the fork.
So there is not a total "rust out."
I know heat expands metal. What do you think of cleaning the rust loosener off and then heating the the ouside ?


WD40 was created exactly for this kind of purpose. Please note that WD40 might damage some rubber seals - depending on the exact composition of the rubber in the seal.
After unblocking, you obviously need to remove all the rust, clean everything with a good solvent, and then apply the suitable grease.
This might be slow process, as you might need to wait and repeat the procedure. I had a problem with the wheel of the car - even though the nuts / bolts were removed, the wheel could not be removed from the car. The solution: they (at the service) applied a generous amount of WD40 in the critical area, and they sent me to drive the car during the weekend (with the nuts / bolts reapplied, of course). The following week I returned to the service, and the wheel came out without a problem.
Additionally, you might be interested in https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/.

The bicycle area at the stackexchange was of no help. All they did was criticize.
